# Button with round edge grid and set disable button color to green

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to have a button with round edge grid and set disable button color to gray, green otherwise. Attached snippet of code. I don't know how to change the default. If I disable my button, I get the output as the image on the left,  however, I want it to look like the image on the right! [image]

```
<Button x:Name="button" Height="30" Width="100"  Margin="825,0,0,0" Background="Transparent" 
        BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent">
    <Button.Content>
        <Border CornerRadius="12.5" Height="25" Width="95" Margin="0" BorderBrush="Gray" 
            BorderThickness="4,4,4,4" Background="Gray">
            <TextBlock Text="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                   Margin="12,0,13,0" Foreground="White"/>
        </Border>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content is only one part of Button. The rest is determined by Template.

If multiple buttons should have custom apperance, the Template should be set in buttons Style. For one button it can be done inplace:

```
<Button x:Name="button" Content="Back" Height="30" Width="100"  Margin="825,0,0,0" Background="Transparent" 
        BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent">
    <Button.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Border CornerRadius="12.5" Height="25" Width="95" Margin="0" BorderBrush="Gray" 
                BorderThickness="4,4,4,4" Background="Gray">
            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                       Margin="12,0,13,0" Foreground="White"/>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

if you are going to reuse the template, declare it as Resource

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="RoundBtn">
        <Border Name="roundBorder" CornerRadius="12.5" Height="25" Width="95" Margin="0" BorderBrush="Gray" 
                BorderThickness="4,4,4,4" Background="Gray">
            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                       Margin="12,0,13,0" Foreground="White"/>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter TargetName="roundBorder" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

and set button Template using resource:

```
<Button x:Name="button" Content="Back" Height="30" Width="100"
        Template="{StaticResource RoundBtn}"
        Margin="825,0,0,0" Background="Transparent" 
        BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent"/>
```

Comment: This is fine but it doesn't change the color of the button to green when disabled! Putting the template into Window resources was really useful for me! If you can incorporate it into the template, It'll be great!

Comment: @user9059547, I modified example with ControlTemplate  in resource - added template trigger, which changes background when buttons is disabled

Comment: `<Setter TargetName="roundBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>`

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly! Just needed to set BorderBrush Value to Green!

Comment: Is there a way to create a button using the above template through the C# code. If so, How can it be done?

Comment: technically it can be done like `var b = new Button(); b.Height = 30; b.Width = 100; /*set other properties*/ b.SetResourceReference(Control.TemplateProperty, "RoundBtn")`; SetResourceReference sets dynamic resource and has alternatives - if you give more details about what you are trying to achieve, there can be other options. it is probably better to create a new question though

Comment: Link to the new question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/49573320/9059547)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.  I've used an outer grid with a blue background so that I could be sure it was all working, but just remove that and move the style to whichever resources you need to.  Explanation as comments within the xaml:

```
<Grid Background="Blue">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <!-- Override the default button style, otherwise you get a grey
             rectangle behind the ellipse when disabled -->
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyButtonStyle">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent" />

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" 
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>  

    <Button x:Name="button" Height="30" Width="100"
            BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" IsEnabled="false"
            Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}">
        <Button.Content>
            <Border CornerRadius="12.5" Height="25" Width="95">
                <Border.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <!-- Button is gray by default, i.e. when enabled -->
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                            <!-- If the button becomes disabled then it becomes green -->
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Border.Style>
                <TextBlock Text="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           Foreground="White"/>
            </Border>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```