# Binding button content to different value from database

Tags: c#, wpf, button, binding

I need to fill buttons content with different values from database for example i will have movie database and few buttons. Each one of them (button) will have different movie name and when i click on it, it will show me new window with other information's about that clicked movie from database, like movie description, directors, actors etc.

I read about similar kind of problem, and thought about create a list and bind every button to each of position, but im not sure is it good solution. Do you have any advice or maybe code examples how to deal with it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: [this mine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49574684/1506454) shows relatively simple approach. instead of `MessageBox.Show` you can open new window

Comment: Thank you for help i will try it

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I will approach a task as yours. I'll have a list of the movies bound to a dropdown or to a table. Rather than have buttons floating around your page. Then on the index change event of the dropdown or on row click of the table I will get the ID of the movie and retrieve all the extra information about movie displayed on a pop-up window. This will be a better design. Hope this helps.